Can Celery Be Used for Background Tasks Without Redis in Production?
I have an API that needs to upload large files to S3, with file sizes close to 10GB. I want to handle this as a background task and am considering using Celery. However, the client won't accept the additional cost of using a Redis service.
Is it possible to implement this background task without using Redis? Any resources for this would be appreciated.
